# MySQL: select elements in one table but not in another table, Im getting wrong results

Tags: mysql

I have the two following tables named tableA and tableB respectively

[image]

[image]

tableB contain names of all places.I want to select all Facilities and week from where are facility is in tableA but not in tableB.
Table below shows what im intending to achieve

[image]

MySql query below is giving wrong results

```
 select tableA.Week ,tableB.Place 
    from tableA
    RIGHT JOIN tableB
    on tableA.Place <> tableB.Place
```

Comment: Do you have another table with a list of `weeks` you want (the same way that tableB is just a list of Facitilies)? Otherwise I don't think there's a relationship between "missing weeks" and Facilities, because right now there's no way to tell that weeks are just 1-3 instead of, for example, weeks 1-5. (In this example, A, B, and C should all be returned for weeks 4 and 5 too.) But if you had a "weeks" table, then you can join that with tableA, and then join with tableB where week IS NULL (or something similar).

Comment: Your request is not clear.
Can you print the differents columns of both tables ? I think you are looking for something like : select a.week, a.place from tableA a where a.place not in (select b.place from tableB b)

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of the distinct `Week`s of `TableA` to `TableB` and `NOT EXISTS` to get the result that you want:

```
SELECT w.Week, b.Place
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Week FROM TableA) w
CROSS JOIN TableB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA a WHERE a.Week = w.Week AND a.Place = b.Place)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=383f3450996e90948a8f46e5ae2af6d7).
Results:

| Week | Place |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |